# How to install Sage if I already have Jupyter

Tags: windows, installation, jupyter-notebook, sage

Sorry for my bad english

Is there some way that I could have Sagemath in Jupyter Notebook without installing completely Sagemath by itself?

I have Windows 10 and I had trouble trying to install Sagemath on other computer some time ago, so I won't try it again

Comment: According to the official instruction, you have to install Sage with WSL if your operating system is Windows.